# I don't know what going on

Tags: npm

I just want to know what is going, whenever I download some react code from github (because I want to check the output for inspiration) and run it using npm start, I see this in the terminal.

What should I do?

```
sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! todo-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the todo-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/markcornejo/.npm/_logs/2021-05-20T09_35_52_922Z-debug.log
Marks-Air:todo-react-master markcornejo$
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Git or GitHub. Or react, really. The message comes from `npm`  and it tells you what to do.

Comment: So, in the future: "What should I do?" – first read the error message, especially when it has a hint on what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install` before `npm start`, to ensure all the dependencies are installed.